# When creating an immutable class, should collections only contain immutable objects?

Tags: java, collections, immutability, mutable

Currently studying for an exam... ran into this question on a past paper.

> Consider the following Student and Tutor classes:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(String name, String course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

Tutor:

```
public final class Tutor {
    private String name;
    private final Set<Student> tutees;

    public Tutor(String name, Student[] students) {
        this.name = name;
        tutees = new HashSet<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            tutees.add(students[i]);
        }
    }

    public Set<Student> getTutees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(tutees);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

> Re-write the Tutor class to make it immutable(without modifying the Student class).

I know that the name field should have the `final` modifier to ensure thread safety.

If the tutees `Set` contains mutable Student Objects and the Student class cannot be changed then how do we make the class immutable? Perhaps creating a clone of the Set and upon every call to the `getTutees` method clear `tutees` and add the cloned elements to it?

**Or is it already immutable despite the collection containing mutable objects?**

Comment: There are many definitions of immutable, so only the author of the test knows what they meant. Maybe they don't care about the contained objects. Or maybe they expect you to create copies of the students when you return the unmodifiable set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The members of the collection also need to be immutable. Unmodifiable only means that no elements can be added or removed.

Even if the collection is unmodifiable, once code accessing it has a reference to an element belonging to that collection, then if that element is not immutable then it can be changed.

If the getter for the collection returns a defensive copy, making a new Set referencing new Student objects and returning that instead of the original set, then that will make the collection immutable.

```
public Set<Student> getTutees() {
    Set newSet = new HashSet();
    for (Student tutee : tutees) {
        newSet.add(new Student(tutee.getName(), tutee.getCourse()));
    }
    return newSet;
}
```

Adding an example here to show that using `Collections.unmodifiableSet` is not sufficient for this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ImmutabilityExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Joe", "Underwater Basketweaving 101");
        Tutor tutor = new Tutor("Bill", new Student[] {student});
        Set<Student> students = tutor.getTutees();
        System.out.println("before=" + students);
        students.iterator().next().setName("Mary");
        System.out.println("" + tutor.getTutees());
    }
}

class Student {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(String name, String course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Student, name=" + name + ", course=" + course;
    }
}

final class Tutor {
    private String name;
    private final Set<Student> tutees;

    public Tutor(String name, Student[] students) {
        this.name = name;
        tutees = new HashSet<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            tutees.add(students[i]);
        }
    }

    public Set<Student> getTutees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(tutees);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The output for this is:

```
before=[Student, name=Joe, course=Underwater Basketweaving 101]
[Student, name=Mary, course=Underwater Basketweaving 101]
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That will return references to the same Student objects, allowing them to be directly modified, so the Tutor class would not in fact be immutable.

Comment: @VGR, yes, sorry. I thought only about an immutable collection

Comment: Thankyou. That's what I assumed and I think that is what the question is looking for. Just to add the correct for each loop is: ` for (Student tutee : tutees)`

Comment: There's a nice method called Collections.unmodifiableSet(set) that will put it in a set that won't allow modification.

Comment: @Chill That stops the set from being modified (i.e. cannot add or remove elements) however you can still modify the mutable elements within the set.

Comment: Right. It's just something that also helps "remind" users of your immutable object that it is immutable.

Comment: @Chill: the references contained in the collection are unmodifiable. so if the references are to immutable objects then it would be ok.

Comment: Might be too late - but still.... Unless you perform a defensive copy in the constructor (like you do in the getter), a Student instance can still change externally. That would make a Tutor mutable (the mutability can be observed externally)

Answer (score 2):

I know I am getting too deeper into what it seems to be not more than a homework question, but...

Premises:

1. `Tutor` contains instances of `Student`.
2. We want `Tutor` to be immutable. Thus, it implies that the contained instances of `Student` must be immutable too.
3. We can't make `Student` immutable.

So, what are our chances?

1. We could make `Tutor` return shallow copies of the `Student` instancies. However, this implies that the system will offer a strange, unexpected behaviour to the client. Imagine this code:

```
    Tutor tutor=new Tutor(...);
    Set students=tutor.getTutees();
    Student student=students.iterator().next();
    student.setCourse("1");
    ...
    Set students=tutor.getTutees();
    Student student=students.iterator().next();
    if (!student.getCourse().equals("1"))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("What the hell??? I already set it before!!!");
    }
```

IMHO, the immutability is not worth the confussion we induce the client code to.

2. We could either *extend* Student and override the setters to turn them off:

```
    class MyStudent extends Student
    {
        public MyStudent(...)
        {
            super(...);
        }

        @Override
        public void setCourse(String s)
        {
            // Prevent modification silently.
        }

        @Override
        public void setName(String s)
        {
            // Even worse: Prevent modification through runtime exceptions:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
```

Same objection as before: The client code would still compile OK, but the behaviour would be strange and unexpected according to the standard javabean conventions.

My conclusion: Immutability is a *design* issue (not a programming issue), because if a class is immutable, it **should have no setters at all**.

So, altough the problem has some technically valid solutions, it is **unsolvable** in terms of good practices.